# Alternatives to sockets

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming

I read a definition of sockets as *"the most commonly used API for UDP/TCP connexions"* (school material).
It makes me curious to know if there are alternatives, and have been unable to find one yet. **I don't mean added abstraction layers** (such as RPC or RMI for example), **or things using a different network stack**, but using something else that fullfills the same role in a different way.

I might have misunderstood the role of the socket too, I would consider it is fits in the session OSI layer, or maybe the transport one ? I'm not really sure about that.

I don't plan on using those alternatives, and I understand how convenient sockets are, I was just wondering.

Thanks for your interest

Comment: I have checked this thread, but
1) it's old and maybe new projects are born since then
2) it's specific to C# (I do not care about the language used)
3) it seems like the author was satisfied with an added abstraction layer. I have specified that I am looking for **alternatives**, not added abstractions (which I already have in mind).
Thanks for checking though :)

Comment: `using a different network stack` but that's exactly what it is. A different network stack with a different implementation of e.g. TCP and different APIs. There is no fundamental reason there have to be `listen` and `bind` functions.

Comment: I see, what I should have actually been looking for was an other implementation of sockets, and not an alternative to it I guess.
Thanks for wiring my brain ;D

Comment: You should look at XTI (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X/Open_Transport_Interface) nee STREAMS.

Comment: Thanks alot, this is exactly what I was looking for. So Sockets are inherited from BSD!
I don't know how to set this question as solved considering you answered as a comment...

Comment: There is yet another alternative API to the low-level network programming. It is used in Plan 9 operating system. It uses `dial`, `announce`, `accept` and `reject` functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't plan to use a different network stack, I think the answer is no. The reason behind this is that the socket is implemented tightly with the network stack. TCP and UDP, for example, both use socket to save the unsent data and received data . You can definitely implement some APIs to read data from and write data to those buffers. But I can't see any advantage in doing this, and those APIs are really built upon socket.

Comment: No they're not. The TLI interface has nothing to do with the Sockets interface. And the Socket interface is used for Unix domain sockets as well as TCP and UDP so it is not 'tightly coupled' to it at all.

Comment: I think A. Grenouilloux is asking an alternative socket implements that can run on the same network stack. In Linux system, TCP or UDP directly put data in the socket buffer, So if you don't change the network stack, how can you bypass this?